# What is the the parent word on which the current-word depend?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm using SpaCy to trace the word dependency.
I can see the dependency type but not the 'parent-word' on which it is dependent.

```
In [79]: [ (i.text, i.dep_) for i in list(doc.sents)[3] ]
Out[79]: 
[(u'The', u'det'),
 (u'TV', u'nsubj'),
(u'is', u'ROOT'),
(u'50', u'nummod'),
(u'inch', u'compound'),
(u'plasma', u'attr'),
(u'.', u'punct'),
(u'\n', u'')]
```

How can I find word on which the current-word depend ?

Comment: The Token attribute that stores the index of a given token's syntactic governor (or head) is called `head`. So add `i.head`to your output. You can also add `i.head.text`, `i.head.pos_` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  ongenz said **.head** is the solution ...

Comment: Careful: it is an attribute not a method, so there are no parentheses: `.head`.